# WPF datagridtextcolumn vertical content alignment not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am looking for some help on WPF UI.

1. I would like to have my data grid's content all to be shown in center of the column.
2. In order to look nice in UI, I need the `datagridtextboxcolumn` and
   `datagridtemplatecolumn` (combo box) width and height fits the columns.

Currently, I already implement the style of Content Presenter with Stretch VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment which success make the data fits to the columns width and height.

And it success showing the data horizontally center after I set setter property of `TextBlock.TextAlignment`.

But the data is not showing in the center vertically even though I already set the setter property of Vertical Content Alignment to Center.

So, I need experts to give me some advices on making the data shown in center vertically and horizontally with stretching the width height to fits the columns.

Below is my style code

```
    <Style x:Key="Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering"
    TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And below will be my `DataGrid` implementation code:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridAccount" RowHeight="27" MinRowHeight="50" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" MinColumnWidth="150" RowHeaderWidth="0" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellStyle="{StaticResource Body_Content_DataGrid_Centering}" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding username}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Username" Width="1*">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Entry Level" Width="1*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding entryLevel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource entryLevel}"
                                                  SelectedItem="{Binding entryLevel}" Margin="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Current Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/reRHc.jpg

Expected Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag13j.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose, that your `Textblock` inside the `GridCells` are not taking the whole space of the cell. You set the `VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` for the GridCell, but not for the `TextBlock` inside this Cell. So you should add both Alignments to the `TextBlock` Style inside the Cells as well.

Comment: But I can see that the Textblock had already take the effect of Stretch for VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAligment as shown in http://imgur.com/a/dGVWw

Just I wonder why the VerticalContentAlignment does not effect on textblock as u can see the text is always on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `VerticalAlignment={TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}` on your ContentPresenter

Comment: Hi, the code works on the textblock which shown in center but it caused the combobox not stretch to fits column anymore. Any advices? Thanks

Comment: Advices? No. Workaround, yes. Try setting RowHeight of your DataGrid to a certain value, then set Height of your ComboBox in the cell to the same value. I'd love to help you do this in a proper way, to style everything in one place and apply it to a cell as a template, but as far as I know, there is no such possibility in DataGrids. I have been struggling with this just lately and found out that many parts of DataGrids can't be styled from ContentTemplate, because they don't inherit from Control class. Basically styling DataGrid is pain in the ass and you will have to do workarounds anyway...